# Spring boot not registering on promethes end point

Tags: spring-boot, grafana, prometheus

I am trying to configure Prometheus and Grafana with spring boot.

```
@Configuration
@EnableSpringBootMetricsCollector
public class MetricsConfiguration {

    /**
     * Register common tags application instead of job. This application tag is
     * needed for Grafana dashboard.
     *
     * @return registry with registered tags.
     */

    @Value("${spring.application.name}")
    private String applicationName;

    @Value("${spring.profiles.active}")
    private String environment;


    @Bean
    public MeterRegistryCustomizer<MeterRegistry> metricsCommonTags() {
        return registry -> {
            registry.config().commonTags("application", applicationName, "environment", environment)
                    .meterFilter(getDefualtConfig());
        };
    }

    private MeterFilter getDefualtConfig() {
        return new MeterFilter() {
            @Override
            public DistributionStatisticConfig configure(Meter.Id id, DistributionStatisticConfig config) {
                return DistributionStatisticConfig.builder().percentilesHistogram(true).percentiles(0.95, 0.99).build()
                        .merge(config);
            }
        };
    }

}
```

while running the application I am able to see traing on **localhost:8080/prometheus** url.

but same I am not able to see on **localhost:9090/metrics** url which is Prometheus URL.

I have added the configuration in prometheus.yml and restarted the Prometheus.

```
- job_name: 'my-api'
    scrape_interval: 10s
    metrics_path: '/prometheus'
    target_groups:
       - targets: ['localhost:8080']
```

Comment: Is this Spring-Boot `1.5.x` used in conjunction with `micrometer-spring-legacy`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending 2 hours found the solution,
we were using basic auth for all health points also
The issue was that I was not setting up basic auth in my proemtheus.yml

```
- job_name: 'my-api'
    scrape_interval: 10s
    metrics_path: '/prometheus'
    target_groups:
       - targets: ['localhost:8080']
    basic_auth:
      username: test
      password: test
```

Comment: I am still confused why you are mixing `Micrometer` and the Prometheus "client_java" libraries. (because you are using `@EnableSpringBootMetricsCollector`) `Micrometer` has support for Prometheus metrics and the endpoint by including `micrometer-registry-prometheus` in your project.

Comment: Can I get Example for that without using micrometer, because I went through many examples

Comment: I rather meant the other way around. When you are using Spring Boot, there's really no reason not to use `Micrometer`. Please refer to the [documentation](http://micrometer.io/docs) to get started or hop on by the Slack channel if something is still not clear.